# MariaDB of EC2 instance is created in MySQL Workbench but not in DBeaver

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, dbeaver

I installed Maria db in ec2 now and created a user named id: user, password: user to grant all permissions. In mysql workbench, I succeeded in creating a connection. But there's an error on DBeaver

```
Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=15.164.221.164)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection timed out: no further information
  Connection timed out: no further information
  Connection timed out: no further information
```

This is what the error is about.

On DBeaver, I clicked the new connection button to create Connection, on Server Host, ip on my ec2 server, 3306 on port, test on database, user on user name, user on password, and pressed Finish button on Local Client, but I got that error. What should I do?

This is my Connection information in MySQL Workbench
[Connection information in MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNCD2.png)

And this is my screen in DBeaver
[in DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCq3T.png)